# Advanced splash sreen how can i use it in my code

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I know how to make an advanced splash screen in wxpython but i don't know how exactly put in my application.I am a bit confused.
Can anyone help to understand better what is going on?
Below there is a simple code to create a splash screen.Thanks!!!

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.advancedsplash as AS

app = wx.App(0)

frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, "AdvancedSplash Test")

imagePath = "my_splash_image.png"
bitmap = wx.Bitmap(imagePath, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
shadow = wx.WHITE

splash = AS.AdvancedSplash(frame, bitmap=bitmap, timeout=5000,
                           agwStyle=AS.AS_TIMEOUT |
                           AS.AS_CENTER_ON_PARENT |
                           AS.AS_SHADOW_BITMAP,
                           shadowcolour=shadow)

app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does just what it's told to: it creates a splash screen, shows it for 5 seconds and then goes to the main loop. You might have forgotten to add `frame.Show()` to the code to actually show the main frame and (optionally) `frame.Center()` to center the frame to the screen.

To ensure the frame doesn't lose focus after splash screen destroys, I recommend you first to show splash screen (with `parent=None`) and then initialize the frame:

```
app = wx.App(0)
imagePath = "my_splash_image.png"
bitmap = wx.Bitmap(imagePath, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
shadow = wx.WHITE
splash = AS.AdvancedSplash(None, bitmap=bitmap, timeout=5000,
                           agwStyle=AS.AS_TIMEOUT |
                           AS.AS_CENTER_ON_PARENT |
                           AS.AS_SHADOW_BITMAP,
                           shadowcolour=shadow)
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, "AdvancedSplash Test")
frame.Center()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```